# How would i conduct a filtered search of songs in the MediaStore?

Tags: java, android, android-search

Currently, the song is only displayed if the user types in the exact song name, as well as it having to be case sensitive. In the `onQueryTextChange` function, the user input is sent to a separate function which retrieves all the songs with that specific title name like this...

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = {songName};
```

`songName` is the user input received from the `SearchView`.

So is there another way which would filter the songs out as the input is changed, rather than having them search for the exact song name?

Answer (score 0):

If you collect all song from device initially, store it in a list, and then apply search filter then it will return all songs having that word or alphabate.